# echo >>regular_file vs echo >>&fd: one closes, other does not

Tags: bash, files, zsh, echo, file-descriptors

In my observation, echo to regular file `echo >>regular_file` opens the file, appends to it, and then closes the file. Whereas echo to an open file descriptor `echo >>&fd`* doesn't close it. Is this behavior documented somewhere in bash/zsh manuals?

* here fd can be a number like `3`.

Comment: There is no *echo to an open file descriptor*. The command `echo Hello >>&3` will write to file `3` (in zsh only. In bash there is a similar `&>>`). There is no `fd` to close, but the file yes, gets closed.

Answer (score 2):

The syntax `echo >>&fd` is not defined by POSIX, Bash or zsh, I assume you meant `echo >&fd`. Both operations involve file descriptor duplication, but the first one involves first opening the specified file. In `echo >>regular_file` (which is equivalent to `echo 1>>regular_file`, where fd `1` is standard output) the shell first `open`s `regular_file`, this operation returns a file descriptor, then the returned fd is `dup`licated to standard output fd `1`, and the former is closed. After the command finishes execution, fd `1` is "restored" (not necessarily done if a `fork` is made, but whatever way it's done, fd `1` refers to the same file it referred to before executing the command).

The second command `echo >&fd` (again, equivalent to `echo 1>&fd`) only duplicates `fd` to stdout and **does not close `fd`**. Again, standard output is restored after execution of the command.

It's clearer to refer to the first operation as redirection and the second one as file descriptor duplication, as documented by POSIX shell command language, and other shells.